# Wordpress site flashes white screen when switching pages

Tags: wordpress, pageload

I have a wordpress site that I am building that is giving me some problems.  When switching pages, the screen goes white before loading the next page.  It should hold the background, header and footer, with only the content area changing.  It was working.  I was having some problems with image sizes, so I resized and reuploaded images.  After doing that the problem appeared.  I have deactivated all plugins and reactivated one by one.  It appears as though it is the revolution slider plugin that is causing the issue.  None of the photos that I resized were in any of the sliders, but it was working fine before the alterations. I deactivated and deleted the plugin. I reinstalled a fresh copy and rebuilt the sliders.  The problem still exists.

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this issue.  It looks horrible!

Comment: It's probably a cache related reason why the change has happened since you resized all images. Do you require the pages to be separate pages, or could you just use PHP and have all the content on one page?

Comment: It is a wordpress site using a purchased theme, so each page is built separately.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you. Certainly for me, I wouldn't be trying to get such a smooth transition, as I don't think it could ever be done. Especially not when just using a simple Wordpress setup. But I'm sure some others may have better ideas!

Comment: I love playing `guess what my issue is` game! I will guess your ajax code broke and now pages aren't doing ajax requests but loading pages normally. since it doesn't seem like you aren't very touchy with the code, I did assume in the theme option there is a checkbox for Loading pages without refreshing.

Comment: I am sorry that I don't have more knowledge as to what the problem is.  If I did, I wouldn't be posting the question here.  All I know is that it was working fine, I made some image adjustments and now it's not working.  I am sorry for my frustration...I just wish I could figure this out.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site (even if you delete it later)? That would be a big help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: "It should hold the background, header and footer, with only the content area changing" - what makes you think only the content area should change? This isn't how webpages work. Everything changes when you load a new URL

Comment: @henrywright unless its a ajaxload!

Comment: @vico that's why I asked "what makes you think only the content area should change?" If I'd had gotten a response such as "Ajax" then that could explain why the content isn't expected to change. BUT, without any info on whether Ajax is being used, we must assume it isn't.